# How to retain symbol tables in DLL built from C++ in R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, r-package

I am trying to profile C++ code that is part of an R package, using 64-bit Windows 10 and R4.1.2.

I've used `PKG_CXXFLAGS = -g` to retain debugging information, but I also need to retain the symbol table in the DLL.  The g++ linker is running with the `-s` flag that "removes all symbol table and relocation information from the executable"; whilst I can add additional arguments using the `PKG_LIBS` entry of my Makevars file (at `tools::makevars_user()`), I haven't found a way to override the `-s` flag, or better yet to stop it being included in the first place.
Running `R CMD config --all` shows that the `-s -static-libgcc` flags I'm seeing in my linker command are not being produced by a Makevars variable.

I have a vague recollection of accomplishing this before using `-S`, perhaps in conjunction with a SHLIB Makevars variable, but this seems to [cancel linking entirely](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options).

How can I retain symbols in order to profile my C++ code?

Comment: You are likely up against R behavior here; we do not set anything for `Rcpp` (as CRAN Policy and WRE would not let us anyway).  I would likely start by editing `R.home("etc/Makeconf")` -- and I am a little surprised you have `-s` in there.  What OS / distro do you use for R?

Comment: Thanks Dirk - I found this just as you commented.  I'm using Windows 10; `-s` is added to `DLLFLAGS` if `DEBUG` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to track down the origin of the `-s` flag to the `$(R_HOME}/etc$(R_ARCH)/Makeconf` file.  This can therefore be overwritten by setting `DLLFLAGS=`, which will also remove any other flags.

On Windows 10, my version of `$(R_HOME}/etc$(R_ARCH)/Makeconf` adds `DLLFLAGS += -static-libgcc`, so I've added the line `DLLFLAGS = -static-libgcc` to my `$Home/.R/Makeconf` file to overwrite the original `-s` flag without losing other options.

(This said, my profiler is still not identifying the lines in which time is being spent...)